# How do I create a package and import it?

Tags: python, import, package, init

I have:

```
├── main.py
├── /subFolder
│   └── __init__.py
│   └── one.py
│   └── two.py
```

My main.py looks like this:

```
from subFolder import *
print(oneString())
print(twoString())
```

My `__init__.py` looks like this:

```
__all__ = ["one", "two"]
```

My `one.py` looks like this:

```
from two import *
def oneString():
   return "one"
```

My `two.py` looks like this:

```
def twoString():
   return "two"
```

When I run it gives me **ModuleNotFoundError**. Also, when I right-click on `__all__ = ["one", "two"]`it says: no definition found. Seems like my `__all__` does not work. I want to create a package of subFolder so I can write: `import subFolder` instead of `from subFolder import *`

Comment: Consider accepting the answer too if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
from subFolder import *
print(oneString())
print(twoString())
```

should be

```
from subFolder import *
print(one.oneString())
print(two.twoString())
```

You have imported the files `one.py` and `two.py` using from `subFolder import *`. To use the functions defined inside the files, you need to use `one.oneString()` i.e. the filename followed by the function name.